# Stuck on Indefinite Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Please help me. I have been stuck on this for ages :(

$$\int \frac{1}{13\cos x+ 12}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

I appreciate any and all help. Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT:

For the integrals of the form $\displaystyle\frac1{a\sin x+b\cos x+c},$  where $a,b,c$ are arbitrary constants

try setting $\displaystyle\tan\frac x2=t$ and use  [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution)

Comment: This was an excellent hint. Solving the problem was only secondary in comparison to learning a new technique for integration. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 7):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{13\cos x+12}dx = \int\frac{1}{13(1+\cos x)-1}dx$$

Now Using $$\displaystyle 1+\cos x = 2\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}\;,$$ we get

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{1}{26\cos^2 \frac{x}{2}-1}dx$$
Now Divide both $\bf{N_{r}}$ and $\bf{D_{r}}$ by $\displaystyle \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}$

$$\displaystyle \int\frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{26-1-\tan^2 \frac{x}{2}}dx = \int\frac{\sec^2 \frac{x}{2}}{5^2-\tan^2\frac{x}{2}}dx$$

Now Let $\displaystyle \tan \frac{x}{2} = t\;,$ Then $\displaystyle \sec^2\frac{x}{2}dx = 2dt$

So Integral is $$\displaystyle 2\int\frac{1}{5^2-t^2}dt = \frac{1}{10}\ln \left|\frac{5+t}{5-t}\right|+\mathbb{C}$$

Where $\displaystyle t = \cos^2 \frac{x}{2}$

Comment: Was going to add this as a separate answer:) Good job.

Comment: Soory lab bhattacharjee actually I did not seen yrs Hint. Thanks

Comment: Nothing to be sorry for.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
\begin{align}
&\color{#66f}{\large\int{1 \over 13\cos\pars{x} + 12}\,\dd x}
=\int{1 \over 26\cos^{2}\pars{x/2} - 1}\,\dd x
=\int{\sec^{2}\pars{x/2} \over 26 - \sec^{2}\pars{x/2}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=\
\overbrace{\int{\sec^{2}\pars{x/2} \over 25 - \tan^{2}\pars{x/2}}\,\dd x}
^{\ds{\tan\pars{x/2} \equiv t}}\ =\
2\int{\dd t \over 25 - t^{2}}
={1 \over 5}\int\pars{{1 \over t + 5} - {1 \over t - 5}}\,\dd t
\\[3mm]&={1 \over 5}\,\ln\pars{\verts{t + 5 \over t - 5}}
=\color{#66f}{\large%
{1 \over 5}\,\ln\pars{\verts{\tan\pars{x/2} + 5 \over \tan\pars{x/2} - 5}}}
+ \mbox{a constant.}
\end{align}